# Polyline not visible Android Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am a little bit confused since everything seems to be alright with the code.
The problem is that the polyline won't show up on the map.

Here is the function that I call to place polyline everytime I receive a location

(I added markers in a similar way and they work great)

```
private void addPolylineLocationOnMap(LatLng newLoc)
{
    PolylineOptions poly = new PolylineOptions()
                                    .add(newLoc)
                                    .color(Color.BLUE)
                                    .width(5)
                                    .visible(true)
                                    .zIndex(30);

    googleMap.addPolyline(poly);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Polyline` needs multiple points!

For example, pass an `ArrayList<LatLng>` to your method and use `addAll()` rather than just `add()`.

From the `PolylineOptions` documentation:

```
add(LatLng... points) : Adds vertices to the end of the polyline being built.
```

Alternatively, you can keep a reference to one `Polyline` and use `add()` to add points to it as you receive them.

Add poly as an instance variable in your class:

```
PolylineOptions poly;
```

Then in `onCreate()` (or wherever you set up the map):

```
poly = new PolylineOptions()
    .color(Color.BLUE)
    .width(5)
    .visible(true)
    .zIndex(30);

googleMap.addPolyline(poly);
```

Then as you receive more points:

```
poly.add(newLoc);
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to add the polyline dynamically as I am receiving the location points. That is why I want to add them one by one

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your request!

Comment: addAll method seems to be working allright (I use it in my onResume method to reconstruct the polyline). However, I tried to instantiate a global PolylineOptions variable in my method for initializing the map and adding points as I receive them with the add method, but this does not seem to be working

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-add the polyline to the googleMap after adding to it?  After poly.add(newLoc), googleMap.addPolyline(poly)?  This reaches the end of my recollection of how this works.